# Custom interpolation / minimization function (aka curve fitting) any library

Tags: python, scipy, minimization, lmfit

I usually work with ROOT and its powerful MINUIT interpolation classes in a C++ environment. For reason related to plotting and ease of data handling, I switched recently to Python 3.8. The problem is that I can't find a library that allows me to set my custom interpolation function (1D by now, multivariate in the future)! `Scipy` and `Pandas` have preset `methods`, and I am not aware of other libraries for interpolation. It seems to me quite impossible, therefore I ask you!

What I need to reproduce is something that sounds like this in ROOT:

**DEFINITION OF THE INTERPOLATING FUNCTION**

```
TF1* f3 = new TF1("PECD6", "([0]*x + 0.5*[2]*(5*x*x*x-3*x) +0.125*[4]*(63*x*x*x*x*x-70*x*x*x+15*x)) / (1 + 0.5*[1]*(3*x*x-1) + 0.125*[3]*(35*x*x*x*x-30*x*x+3) + 0.0625*[5]*(231*x*x*x*x*x*x-315*x*x*x*x+105*x*x-5)) +1", -0.9, 0.9);
    f3->SetParameters(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    f3->SetParLimits(0, -1, 1);
    f3->SetParLimits(1, -1, 1);
    f3->SetParLimits(2, -1, 1);
    f3->SetParLimits(3, -1, 1);
    f3->SetParLimits(4, -1, 1);
    f3->SetParLimits(5, -1, 1);
    f3->SetParNames("b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6");
```

as you can see, I am using Legendre polynomials up to the 6th order and I'd like to receive the coefficient, possibly with propagations of error.

**USE OF THE FUNCTION**

```
ratio_genarray[rcounter]->Fit("PECD6", "QR");
fit1[k] = ratio_genarray[rcounter]->GetFunction("PECD6");
```

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: I have found something like this

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: I have found another interesting library based on scipy: LMFIT Non-Linear Least-Squares Minimization and Curve-Fitting for Python
https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [iminuit](https://iminuit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). You'd need to rearrange your C++ syntax to iminuit's Python syntax, but from there on, it's a minimal change because it *is* MINUIT.

(LMFIT also looks promising, but since you're already using MINUIT, it would be a smoother transition to iminuit.)

Comment: how to implement the standard error on a custom least square function?

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/scikit-hep/iminuit/blob/master/tutorial/generic_least_squares_function.ipynb

Comment: on top of the last question: why a myTH2D.values is equal to myTH2D.variances ? Is it because of my original dataset?

Comment: Histogram values would be equal to its variances if they are simple counts (Poisson statistics). In fact, that's the usual case. For a ROOT histogram, this means that it has no Sumw2.